# Fast check whether one vector is part of another vector

Tags: r, vector

I have a list of vectors, say `vecs = list(vec1=1:3, vec2=1:5, vec3=2:6, vec4=1:7)`. I want to remove all the list members that if it is contained in another list member. For example, `vecs$vec1` is part of `vecs$vec2`, (or `vecs$vec4`), so I want to remove it.

I want a very fast implementation, because `length(vecs)` is very big. What I did is first sort `vecs` member by length `vecs = vecs[ order(unlist(lapply(vecs, length))) ]`, then for `check_member = vecs[i]`, check whether it is part of `vecs[ i+1 ], vecs[ i+2 ]...` .Is there any better strategy? Complete code:

```
vecs = list(vec1=1:3, vec2=1:5, vec3=2:6, vec4=1:7, vec5=2:3)
vecs = vecs[ order(unlist(lapply(vecs, length))) ] ##sort by member length
vecs_len = length(vecs)
toRemove = numeric(vecs_len ) ##record whether to remove this member
for( i in 1:(vecs_len-1 ))
for( j in (i+1):(vecs_len ))
{
   if( length( setdiff(vecs[[i]],vecs[[j]]) )==0  ) {toRemove[i] = 1; break} ##check whether vecs[[i]] is part of vecs[[j]]

}
vecs = vecs[!toRemove]
```

Comment: Can you show the actual code you used?

Comment: Do your vectors always contain integers and if so, what is the range of the union (here 1 through 7)? Please also give details about how big your list is and how long the vectors are.

Comment: @flodel Not really integers only. Just an example here. In fact are vectors of strings. unique( unlist(vecs) ) > 1e4; But if you have good idea for integers, then the strings can be named by integer and it works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please try this on your large data. I am starting from vectors of characters as you clarified in your comment. I am also assuming the vectors do not contain duplicates (easy to fix via `lapply(vecs, unique)` if they do)

```
vecs <- list(vec1=letters[1:3],
             vec2=letters[1:5],
             vec3=letters[2:6],
             vec4=letters[1:7])
```

First, turn your data into a list of factors (i.e. integers) sharing the same levels:

```
vlevels <- unique(unlist(vecs))
nlev    <- length(vlevels)
fvecs   <- lapply(vecs, factor, levels = vlevels)
```

Then, I convert the data into a matrix of `0` and `1` for included/not-included:

```
vtabs <- vapply(fvecs, tabulate, integer(nlev), nbins = nlev)
#      vec1 vec2 vec3 vec4
# [1,]    1    1    0    1
# [2,]    1    1    1    1
# [3,]    1    1    1    1
# [4,]    0    1    1    1
# [5,]    0    1    1    1
# [6,]    0    0    1    1
# [7,]    0    0    0    1
```

Next, I compute the crossproduct to see how many elements two vectors have in common, and compare with the length of each vector to decide whether the first one is a subset of the second one.

```
num.match <- crossprod(vtabs)
vlen <- sapply(vecs, length)
is.subset.mat <- num.match == vlen
diag(is.subset.mat) <- FALSE
#       vec1  vec2  vec3  vec4
# vec1 FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
# vec2 FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
# vec3 FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
# vec4 FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

Finally, I sum row-wise to tell if each vector is a subset of any other:

```
is.subset <- rowSums(is.subset.mat) > 0L
# vec1  vec2  vec3  vec4 
# TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
```

You are only left with filtering:

```
out <- vecs[!is.subset]
```

If your initial list is so large that this is too slow, then I would suggest that you run it chunk-by-chunk, then again on the results.

Answer (score 1):

After doing some benchmarking here we can see you could just slightly modify your original code for a nice speedup.  Using `%in%` and `any` is more efficient than `setdiff` and `length`.

```
# Your code
fun1 <- function(vecs){
  vecs_len = length(vecs)
  toRemove = numeric(vecs_len ) ##record whether to remove this member
  for( i in 1:(vecs_len-1 ))
    for( j in (i+1):(vecs_len ))
    {
      if( length( setdiff(vecs[[i]],vecs[[j]]) )==0  ) toRemove[i] = 1 ##check whether vecs[[i]] is part of vecs[[j]]

    }
  vecs = vecs[!toRemove]
  return(vecs)
}

# flodel's code
fun2 <- function(vecs){
  vlevels <- unique(unlist(vecs))
  nlev    <- length(vlevels)
  fvecs   <- lapply(vecs, factor, levels = vlevels)
  vtabs <- vapply(fvecs, tabulate, integer(nlev), nbins = nlev)
  num.match <- crossprod(vtabs)
  vlen <- sapply(vecs, length)
  is.subset.mat <- num.match == vlen
  diag(is.subset.mat) <- FALSE
  is.subset <- rowSums(is.subset.mat) > 0L
  out <- vecs[!is.subset]
  return(out)  
}

# slight modification
fun3 <- function(vecs){
  vecs_len = length(vecs)
  toRemove = numeric(vecs_len ) ##record whether to remove this member
  for( i in 1:(vecs_len-1 ))
    for( j in (i+1):(vecs_len ))
    {
      if( any(vecs[[i]] %in% vecs[[j]])  ) toRemove[i] = 1 ##check whether vecs[[i]] is part of vecs[[j]]

    }
  vecs = vecs[!toRemove]
  return(vecs)
}

microbenchmark(fun1(vecs), fun2(vecs), fun3(vecs), times=100L)
Unit: microseconds
       expr     min       lq      mean   median       uq     max neval
 fun1(vecs) 154.919 166.4245 179.62297 172.5880 180.3950 356.681   100
 fun2(vecs) 220.255 231.5555 279.99874 237.7185 290.9335 609.398   100
 fun3(vecs)  50.544  54.0370  64.86082  57.3250  64.5155 291.345   100
```

Comment: It would make sense to test with large data. I have tried with `alphabet <- do.call(paste0, expand.grid(letters, letters)); 
vecs <- replicate(1000, sample(alphabet, sample(1:300, 1), FALSE), simplify = FALSE)` and it took 28.86, 0.61, and 12.37 respectively.

Comment: I think you meant to use `all`, not `any`. Also, both your code and the OP's only test if "vecs[i] is a subset of vec[j]"; it should also test if "vecs[j] is a subset of vec[i]".

Comment: @flodel, you are correct, a point I overlooked.  Once the data becomes larger, your function does perform much faster.

Answer (score 0):

I think something like the following should work. It will give you a list of those vectors which are subsets of one of the others. It will be a subset of itself - so I only do it for those where it's a subset of a least two vectors (ie, itself and one other). Credit to https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2005-March/068491.html for the %in% function.

```
dfSubsets <- list()

ds <- lapply(vecs,function(x){
        subsets = 0
        lapply( vecs, function(y){
            if(all(x %in% y)){subsets <<- subsets + 1}
        })
        if(subsets > 1){
            dfSubsets <<- c(dfSubsets,list(x))
        }
}
)

dfSubsets
```

If you want a list of the indices of those vectors which are subsets, let me know.

I'm sure dplyr could probably help as well, but I'm not familiar with that.

Apply generally leads to a gain in efficiency - of course, if you only care about if it's the subset of one vector, it will sometimes be faster using a for loop and break, but you can't know that in advance.

This method works for strings or integers.