# R - efficient comparison of subsets of rows between data frames

Tags: r

thank you for any help.

I need to check the total number of matches from the elements of each row of a data frame (df1) on rows of another data frame (df2).

The data frames have different number of columns (5 in the first one versus 6 in the second one, for instance). And there is no exact formation rule for the rows (so I can not find a way of doing this through combinatory analysis)

This routine must check all the rows from the first data frame against all the rows of the second data frame, resulting a total number of occurences by the number of hits.

Not all the possible sums are of interest. Actually I am looking for a specific total (which I call "hits" in this text).

In other words: how many times a subset of each row of df2 of size "hits" can be found in rows of df1.

Here is an example:

```
> ### Example
> ### df1 and df2 here are regularly formed just for illustration purposes
>  
> require(combinat)
> 
> df1 <- as.data.frame(t(combn(6,5)))
> df2 <- as.data.frame(t(combn(7,6)))
> 
> df1
  V1 V2 V3 V4 V5
1  1  2  3  4  5
2  1  2  3  4  6
3  1  2  3  5  6
4  1  2  4  5  6
5  1  3  4  5  6
6  2  3  4  5  6
> 
> df2
  V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6
1  1  2  3  4  5  6
2  1  2  3  4  5  7
3  1  2  3  4  6  7
4  1  2  3  5  6  7
5  1  2  4  5  6  7
6  1  3  4  5  6  7
7  2  3  4  5  6  7
>
```

In this example, please note, for instance, that subsets of size 5, from row #1 of df2 can be found 6 times in the rows of df1. And so on.

I tried something like this:

```
> ### Check how many times subsets of size "hits" from rows from df2 are found in rows of df1
> 
> myfn <- function(dfa,dfb,hits) {
+       sapply(c(1:dim(dfb)[1]),function(y) { sum(c(apply(dfa,1,function(x,i) { sum(x %in% dfb[i,]) },i=y))==hits) })
+   }
>   
> r1 <- myfn(df1,df2,5)
> 
> cbind(df2,"hits.eq.5" = r1)
  V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 hits.eq.5
1  1  2  3  4  5  6         6
2  1  2  3  4  5  7         1
3  1  2  3  4  6  7         1
4  1  2  3  5  6  7         1
5  1  2  4  5  6  7         1
6  1  3  4  5  6  7         1
7  2  3  4  5  6  7         1
```

This seems to do what I need, but **it is too slow!** I need using this routine on large data frames (about 200 K rows)

I am currently using R 3.1.2 GUI 1.65 Mavericks build (6833)

Can anyone provide a faster or more clever way of doing this? Than you again.

Best regards,
Vaccaro

Comment: How many unique values does your data contain? `length(unique(c(unlist(dfa), unlist(dfb))))`. Do the two data.frames only contain integers from `1` to `n` like in your example? If not, what kind of data? This might give you ideas: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27298123/1201032

Comment: Also knowing the exact dimensions of each data.frame is important here. If both data.frames have 2e5 rows then you are looking at 4e10 pairwise comparisons: you'll have to find a compromise between memory usage and computation time.

Comment: Thank you, flodel. The data contains only positive integers from 1 to 99. The size of the data frames is variable: the smallest one has 6 rows. The largest one, has 51 million rows (I am not kidding). The function I presented is slow even with data frames of 50 rows... Again, thank you for any help.

Comment: How are duplicated values in a row to be treated? For instance, if a row of df1 has `(1,2,1,2,3)` and a row of df2 has `(1,2,3,4,5)`, your code will return 5 hits, not 3. Is that what you want?

Comment: Hello, jlhoward. Sorry, I forgot to mention: there is no repeated values in the same row. This is true for both data frames. Thank you for your attention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `apply(...)` on data frames is very inefficient. This is because `apply(...)` takes a matrix as argument, so if you pass a data frame it will coerce that to a matrix. In your example you convert df1 to a matrix every time you call `apply(...)`, which is `nrow(df2)` times.

Also, by using `sapply(1:nrow(df2),...)` and `dfb[i,]` you are using data frame row indexing, which is also very inefficient. You are much better off converting everything to matrix class at the beginning and then using `apply(...)` twice.

Finally, there is no reason to use a call to `c(...)`. `apply(...)` already returns a vector (in this case), so you are just incurring the overhead of another function call to no effect.

Doing these things alone speeds up your code by about a factor of 20.

```
set.seed(1)
nrows <- 100
df1 <- data.frame(matrix(sample(1:5,5*nrows,replace=TRUE),nc=5))
df2 <- data.frame(matrix(sample(1:6,6*nrows,replace=TRUE),nc=6))

myfn <- function(dfa,dfb,hits) {
  sapply(c(1:dim(dfb)[1]),function(y) { sum(c(apply(dfa,1,function(x,i) { sum(x %in% dfb[i,]) },i=y))==hits) })
}
myfn.2 <- function(dfa,dfb,hits) {
  ma <- as.matrix(dfa)
  mb <- as.matrix(dfb)
  apply(mb,1,function(y) { sum(apply(ma,1,function(x) { sum(x %in% y) })==hits) })
}

system.time(r1<-myfn(df1,df2,3))
#    user  system elapsed 
#    1.99    0.00    2.00 
system.time(r2<-myfn.2(df1,df2,3))
#    user  system elapsed 
#    0.09    0.00    0.10 
identical(r1,r2)
# [1] TRUE
```

There is another approach which takes advantage of the fact that R is extremely efficient at manipulating lists. Since a data frame is just a list of vectors, we can improve performance by putting your rows into data frame columns and then using `sapply(..)` on that. This is faster than `myfn.2(...)` above, but only by about 20%.

```
myfn.3 <-function(dfa,dfb,hits) {
  df1.t <- data.frame(t(dfa))   # rows into columns
  df2.t <- data.frame(t(dfb))
  sapply(df2.t,function(col2)sum(sapply(df1.t,function(col1)sum(col1 %in% col2)==hits)))
}
library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(myfn.2(df1,df2,5),myfn.3(df1,df2,5),times=10)
# Unit: milliseconds
#                 expr      min       lq   median       uq      max neval
#  myfn.2(df1, df2, 5) 92.84713 94.06418 96.41835 98.44738 99.88179    10
#  myfn.3(df1, df2, 5) 75.53468 77.44348 79.24123 82.28033 84.12457    10
```

If you really have a dataset with 55MM rows, then I think you need to rethink this problem. I have no idea what you are trying to accomplish, but this seems like a brute force approach.

Comment: Hello, jlhoward, indeed this is a brute force approach (and probably not a clever one). These data frames are not generated by me. They represent probabilistic outcomes from an experiment. The firs one is randomly generated. The second one is the population of outcomes. I am kind of newbie in R and I am not familiar with the efficiency of some commands yet. So, thank you so much for your explanation. I will try with some data frames here and I will let you know the results.

Comment: Hi, jlhoward, myfn.3 worked just fine! Thank you again. Also I managed to reduce redundancies in the data frames so I think I found a viable way of making this data treatment. Thank you all!